# How to determine the c preprocessor flag for the CPPFLAGS?

Tags: 20.04, compiling, fortran

I received a sets of Fortran code from my collaborator. In the `makefile`, there is a line as follows.

```
CPPFLAGS = $(DEF_FLAGS) -DINTEL
```

Because when I used the `make` command in my terminal to compile the Fortran code, some error messages showed up, my collaborator thinks this is probably because my c preprocessor is not from Intel. Therefor, the flag `-DINTEL` needs to be replaced with the proper c preprocessor name.

My question is How to determine the proper c preprocessor flag in this case?

I am running my Ubuntu (64-bit) using the Oracle VM Virtual Box on my Windows 10 laptop.

**Update**

Below is the error message I received after using the `make` command in the terminal. Removing the `-DINTEL` flag leads to the same error message.

```
/usr/bin/cpp  -DSPHERICAL  -P -C -traditional  -DINTEL  ptraj.f > ptraj.F90
gfortran   -c  -O3 -fno-range-check   -I /usr/include ptraj.F90
ptraj.F90:1447:132:

 1447 | EP(IP)),KHL(NODES(1),IK),KHSMTH1(NODES(1),IK),DKHSP(NODES(1),IK)
      |                                                             1

Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
ptraj.F90:1447:132:

 1447 | EP(IP)),KHL(NODES(1),IK),KHSMTH1(NODES(1),IK),DKHSP(NODES(1),IK)
      |                                                             1

Error: Expected array subscript at (1)
ptraj.F90:2628:17:

 2628 |      NODESX = VX(NODES)
      |                 1
Warning: Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)
ptraj.F90:2629:17:

 2629 |      NODESY = VY(NODES)
      |                 1
Warning: Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)
ptraj.F90:2710:7:

 2710 |   CONC(NODES,ZL) = CONC(NODES,ZL) + WEIGHTS / (DELTAZ + 1.0E-20)
      |       1
Warning: Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)
ptraj.F90:2710:24:

 2710 |   CONC(NODES,ZL) = CONC(NODES,ZL) + WEIGHTS / (DELTAZ + 1.0E-20)
      |                        1
Warning: Legacy Extension: REAL array index at (1)
ptraj.F90:1400:76:

 1400 |   CALL INTERP_KV(1,HOST(IP),PDXN(IP),PDYN(IP),PDZN(IP),KPZ,KPPZ,KHR1,KPP,DELZ)
      |                                                                1

Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘kp’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar) [-Wargument-mismatch]
ptraj.F90:1428:95:

 1428 | (1,HOST(IP),PDXN(IP),PDYN(IP),PDZN(IP),HP(IP),EP(IP),KHSMTH1,DKHSP,KHR1,DKHR1)
      |                                                                   1

Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘khout’ at (1) (rank-1 and scalar) [-Wargument-mismatch]
f951: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [makefile:121: ptraj.o] Error 1
```

**Update2**

I added the `-ffixed-line-length-none` flag, the terminal shows the warning:

```
cc1: warning: unknown register name: line-length-none
```

I added the `-ffree-line-length-none` flag, the terminal shows the warning:

```
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-ffree-line-length-none’ is valid for Fortran but not for C
```

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the `-DINTEL` flag? Do you get other errors in that case?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried removing the `-DINTEL` flag, and it leads to the same error.

Comment: ... and what is that error, exactly?

Comment: @steeldriver Please see my updated post. I have provided the error message I received in the terminal. Is the error message not related to the `-DINTEL` flag?

Comment: It may be *indirectly* related to the `-DINTEL` flag, however fundamentally it's because the Fortran source has longer lines than are permitted by the f90 standard I think. You can try adding `-ffixed-line-length-none` / `-ffree-line-length-none` to the `CPPFLAGS` as discussed here [Intel Fortran to GNU Fortran Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34195616/4440445)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you. Please see my updated post. I added the two flags you suggested. They showed a different warning messages, and then the same error. I also followed the answer from the post you suggested, adding `&` symbol to the line of the file where the error points out, but after I edited the file and run `make` in terminal, those `&`  were gone. It seems like some mechanisms are removing those `&` to keep the line as the original one.

Comment: The `&` shouldn't go at the *end* of the long line (where it will just be truncated, like any other character beyond the 132-character limit), it needs to be used to break up the long line into suitably short chunks - see for example [Fortran Wiki - Continuation lines](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines)